# Javascript code working in Mozilla Firefox but not in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I'm facing a little issue with my javascript code. In fact it's working in Firefox but not in Chrome, do you have any idea why I'm facing this issue?

Here is my code:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if($(this).css('background-image')=='url("linktothepng.png")'){
       $(this).parent().remove();
   } 
});
```

Thank you for helping me, have a good day ;)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Have you checked the chrome console to see if you get an error?

Answer (score 3):

chrome will get it as `url(linktothepng.png)` (no quotes)

browsers parse css and format it their own way, it is not advisable to do text matches on those properties, just use a class with that background and check with `hasClass()` to prevent the inconsistency

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `css('background-image')` can be normalised in different ways by different browsers; they're all valid as long as they are equivalent CSS.

You could test for `css('background-image').indexOf('linktothepng.png') != -1` which would work, assuming there isn't another image in use that has `linktothepng.png` as part of its name (which would require a more complicated test).

If possible though, you'd be better off only ever setting that background image by setting a class.

1. Easier to change.
2. Separates the meaning you are ascribing to that image from the fact that the image is how you are representing it.
3. Quicker to find, instead of replacing the test to something like `if($(this).hasClass('the-class-you-use')` remove the test and change the selector to `$('a.the-class-you-use')`.